# Inhomogeneous approximation mod p

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, diophantine-approximation, transcendental-number-theory

I am interested in the following discrete analog of [Kronecker's inhomogeneous approximation theorem](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Kronecker_theorem).

Given $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ distinct residue classes modulo a prime $p$, and further residue classes $y_1,\ldots,y_n$ mod $p$, when can one find $r$ mod $p$ for which $rx_i\equiv y_i+e_i$ mod $p$ where $e_i\in[-\delta p,\delta p]$ is a small error with $\delta\in(0,1)$?

Comment: Interesting question. I can guess a possible form for an answer: consider the set of vectors $\mathbb v$ in $\mathbb F_p^n$ such that $\sum v_ix_i=0$. Let $h$ be the smallest `height' of a non-zero vector. There is a solution provided $\delta>F(h,n)$, where $F$ is a function such that $F(h,n)\to\infty$ as $h\to\infty$. Is this the kind of statement you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I would like some sort of quantitative measure of how independent the $x_i$ need to be in order to find the desired $r$.

Comment: Doesn't that follow from the Peres-Alon theorem regarding Glasner sets?

Comment: This is the sort of theorem I am after, although I would be curious to know if one can do better with additional hypotheses on the $x_i$.